# How to list Resource Groups across Azure Subscriptions using PowerShell?

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm writing a PowerShell script to list Resource Groups across Azure Subscriptions.

```
Get-AzureRmSubscription | 
select -ExpandProperty name |
 % { 
     Get-AzureRmResourceGroup | select -ExpandProperty resourcegroupname
 }
```

This code works. It returns results like this.

```
Resource group 1     
Resource group 2
Resource group 3
```

How can I tweak the code to get the output like below?

```
Subscription 1,Resource group 1     
Subscription 1,Resource group 2
Subscription 2,Resource group 3
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note:

- This **answer uses cmdlets from the *obsolete* `AzureRM` module**, which has since been replaced with the cross-platform `Az` module - see [this announcement](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-powershell-cross-platform-az-module-replacing-azurerm/).
- **[RoadRunner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61680135/45375) has an updated solution** that uses the `Az` module.

---

```
Get-AzureRmSubscription | 
 % { 
   $subscrName = $_.Name
   Select-AzureSubscription -Current -SubscriptionName $name
   (Get-AzureRmResourceGroup).resourcegroupname | % {     
     [pscustomobject] @{
       Subscription = $subscrName
       ResourceGroup = $_
     }
   }
 }
```

<sup>Note: The above changes the session's current subscription. In your real code you may want to restore the previously current one afterwards.</sup>

The above outputs custom objects with `.Subscription` and `.ResourceGroup` properties; if you really only want to output strings, use:
`"$name,$_"`

Comment: @RajeshSwarnkar, fair enough - I've boldfaced the most important phrases (without using a heading), which I feel is sufficient.

Answer (score 10):

Adding to [@mklement's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61679470/how-to-list-resource-groups-across-azure-subscriptions-using-powershell/61679719#61679719) great answer, here is how you would do it with the latest [Azure PowerShell Az module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-3.8.0) instead of AzureRM:

```
Get-AzSubscription | ForEach-Object {
    $subscriptionName = $_.Name
    Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $_.SubscriptionId
    (Get-AzResourceGroup).ResourceGroupName | ForEach-Object {     
        [PSCustomObject] @{
            Subscription = $subscriptionName
            ResourceGroup = $_
        }
    }
}
```

To change to the active subscription, we can change the context with [`Set-AzContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/set-azcontext?view=azps-3.8.0), and pass the `SubscriptionId` From [`Get-AzSubscription`](https://www.bing.com/search?q=Get-AzSubscription&cvid=bf0f3a3220a047e08980e0002e8d2db9&FORM=ANNTA9&PC=U531). Should also be able to get away with passing the subscription name with `Set-AzContext -Subscription $subscriptionName`.

If you want to run AzureRM commands with the Az module, you can run [`Enable-AzureRmAlias`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/enable-azurermalias?view=azps-3.8.0), which allows you to use the AzureRM prefixes with Az modules.

Comment: Thank you @roadRunner. 
I'm little annoyed by that fact that AZ & AzureRm don't work together. I remember one time, some feature was not supported (I guess it was service principal access), so we had to rollback a bunch of stuff. Not sure if it is supported now.

Comment: You can't run them together; however, Az can have an alias to recognize AzureRm. Just run Enable-AzureRmAlias -Scope CurrentUser

Comment: @RaviLobo DreadedForest has a good solution for that. I do suggest trying to move to Az if you can, its the most up to date one.