# Azure NSG, rule deletion based on source IP address PowerShell ideally

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-virtual-network

I need to delete a single NSG rule for a IP that no longer exists as part of a clean-up operation.  Basically any rule that has IP 10.**.**.blah as its source IP in any or our Azure subscriptions should be deleted.

Regretfully however my tiny peanut brain struggles tremendously with PowerShell.  I imagine someone has done something similar and I would be extremely grateful if you could share it.  Then I can attempt to make sense of it, test it and tweak it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

The following script first gets the Network Security Group and the Network Security Group rule config. Then, a loop will go over all the fetched Network Security Group rules and check if the `SourceAddressPrefix` or the `DestinationAddressPrefix` matches the old IP rule you want to remove. Finally, it will save the changes in the Network Security Group configuration.

```
$nsg = Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup -Name $networkSecurityGroupName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
$nsgRules = Get-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -NetworkSecurityGroup $nsg
foreach($nsgRule in $nsgRules){
    if($nsgRule.SourceAddressPrefix -match $oldIpRule){
      Remove-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name $nsgRule.Name -NetworkSecurityGroup $nsg
    }
    elseif($nsgRule.DestinationAddressPrefix -match $oldIpRule){
      Remove-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name $nsgRule.Name -NetworkSecurityGroup $nsg
    }
}
$nsg | Set-AzNetworkSecurityGroup
```

Comment: Thanks for that pal I will work on that, silly question if I wanted to literally hit all resource groups and all security groups.  Could I define variables at the start as follows with powershell?                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
$networkSecurityGroupName = *
$resourceGroupName = *
$resourceGroupName = *

Comment: I don't think so. You can get the list of all resource groups across subscriptions by using the following script suggested on this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/61680135/16887744